# waiting for debugger to connect to the ios simulator

Tags: xamarin.ios, xcframework

I have created a binding library for xamarin.ios which is based on `.xcframework`. I followed this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough. the fact is that when I add a native reference to `release-fat`, I get a message: `waiting for debugger to connect to the ios simulator` and the app doesn't load in the iOS simulator. If I add a link to the `release-iphonesimulator`, the simulator starts and everything works. is there any way to solve this problem?

Reset the simulator does not help.

Because I need to create a library for both the simulator and the device at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to combine `iphoneos` + `iphonesimulator` as a fat framework ?

- Navigate to the build output folder with Release-iphoneos and Release-iphonesimulator subfolders and copy one of the frameworks as an initial version of the final output (fat framework).

  ```
  cp -R "Release-iphoneos" "Release-fat"
  ```
- Combine modules from another build with the fat framework modules

  ```
  cp -R "Release-iphonesimulator/SwiftFrameworkProxy.framework/Modules/SwiftFrameworkProxy.swiftmodule/" "Release-fat/SwiftFrameworkProxy.framework/Modules/SwiftFrameworkProxy.swiftmodule/"
  ```
- Combine iphoneos + iphonesimulator configuration as a fat framework

  ```
  lipo -create -output "Release-fat/SwiftFrameworkProxy.framework/SwiftFrameworkProxy" "Release-iphoneos/SwiftFrameworkProxy.framework/SwiftFrameworkProxy" "Release-iphonesimulator/SwiftFrameworkProxy.framework/SwiftFrameworkProxy"
  ```
- Verify results

  ```
  lipo -info "Release-fat/SwiftFrameworkProxy.framework/SwiftFrameworkProxy"
  ```

Please check Step 12 in the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough#build-a-native-library.

Comment: Yes, I did that. release-fat does not allow the simulator to start. the simulator starts only with release-iphonesimulator. any suggestions?

Comment: It's weird, consider raising the issue on github for better support : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues.